# How to get two SwiftUI sliders to update to and from a third value which represents the ‘single source of truth’ for their respective values

Tags: swiftui, combine

I am very new to Combine and I am trying to get two SwiftUI sliders to update to and from a third value which represents the ‘single source of truth’ for their respective values.

Each slider has a range from 0…1 but uses a different function to determine its value. In the example below, if the true value is 0.5, the first slider sets and gets that directly (0.5) while the second slider uses the value squared (0.25).

The example works, but I get the impression that this isn’t really the proper way to do it. I get infinite recursion if the guard statements are removed in the Model. Can anyone show me the correct way to do this? Thanks!

Here is the Model:

```
import SwiftUI

class Model : ObservableObject{

    @Published var trueValue: CGFloat = 0{
        didSet{
            slider1Value = trueValue
            slider2Value = trueValue * trueValue
        }
    }

    @Published var slider1Value: CGFloat = 0{
        didSet{
            guard oldValue != slider1Value else { return }

            trueValue = slider1Value
        }
    }

    @Published var slider2Value: CGFloat = 0{
        didSet{
            guard oldValue != slider2Value else { return }

            trueValue = slider2Value.squareRoot()
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the ContentView:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var model: Model

    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader{ geometry in
            VStack{
                ProportionalSlider(value: self.$model.slider1Value, width: geometry.size.width - 20)
                    .frame(width: geometry.size.width, height: 18)
                ProportionalSlider(value: self.$model.slider2Value, width: geometry.size.width - 20)
                    .frame(width: geometry.size.width, height: 18)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And here is the ProportionalSlider:

```
struct ProportionalSlider: View {
    @Binding var value: CGFloat
    var width: CGFloat

    var body: some View{
        let gesture =  DragGesture(minimumDistance: 0)
            .onChanged({ mouse in         
                let clamped = min(self.width, max(0, mouse.location.x))
                self.value = clamped/self.width
            })

        return GeometryReader{ geometry in
            ZStack{
                ZStack(alignment: .leading){
                    Capsule().fill(Color.blue).frame(width: self.width, height: 15)
                       .gesture(gesture)
                    Capsule().fill(Color.red).frame(width: self.value * self.width, height: 15)
                       .gesture(gesture)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use one `@Published` property and one computed property:

```
class Model: ObservedObject {
    @Published var linearValue: CGFloat = 0

    var quadraticValue: CGFloat {
        get { linearValue * linearValue }
        set { linearValue = sqrt(newValue) }
    }
}
```

Bind one slider to `$model.linearValue` and bind the other to `$model.quadraticValue`.